# Python two arguments with one raw_input

Tags: python

How can i get two arguments from one call raw_input?

For example, i need to take two lists and transmit them into function.
Something like this:

```
Def foo(list_1, list_2):
    #function code here

list_2,list_1 = raw_input("Enter first and second lists, please")
result = foo(list_1, list_2)
```

Comment: How about you use *two* `raw_input()` calls?

Comment: you would have to do some preprocessing before you send it as 2 arguments to `foo`

Comment: why not just use input?

Comment: why don't you split it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that just by separating them with a comma:

```
user_input = "[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]"
```

And then passing it into `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
In [3]: ast.literal_eval("[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]")
Out[3]: ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

You'll get a tuple of two lists, which you then unpack into two variables:

```
lst1, lst2 = ast.literal_eval("[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]")
```

Answer (score 3):

to obtain 2 arguments, just split it:

```
list_2,list_1 = raw_input("Enter first and second lists, please").split()
```

(that will still be strings, though)